# How to count items in a list that also appear in another list?

Tags: excel

I have two lists in a sheet. One of them contains part of items in another and I want to count all these items. What's the best and simplest approach to write the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [array formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx) like this, entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(D2:D8,B2:B5))
```

[image: count list in another list]

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I want.